# How to pause a custom built interpreter while debugging?

Tags: java, debugging, antlr, antlr4, interpreter

I am developing a new custom programming language to perform some computations on numbers and display the results in a particular format.

For this purpose, I am using Antlr4 for Lexical Analysis and Parsing, and am developing this in Java. I have been able to "execute" the program by overriding the visitor methods generated by Antlr4.

I am now trying to add debugging functionality, and am trying to pause the execution upon hitting a breakpoint and then resume. Apart from this, I also need to support Step Through, Step In, Step Out, and Resume.

Could someone please throw some light on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Usually I would recommend JITing the code and inserting interrupt code 3, then catch with a debugger, but that doesn’t really work here. Instead of what you’re currently doing I would recommend compiling the code into a virtual language which you would then run over sequentially, then you can add code to create breakpoints. Once a breakpoint is triggered in your virtual code the simplest (and most hacky) solution would be to call a dummy function which you place a breakpoint into in your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR4 generated parsers cannot be stopped and resumed in the middle of a parse run. For that use the interpreters that come with the ANTLR4 runtime. They implement a simple ATN walk, which can be stopped at any point and the current ATN state be saved for later resume of the debugger.

I implemented this approach in my [vscode-antlr4](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/GrapsDebugger.ts#L753) extension, which allows to debug arbitrary ANTLR4 grammars. See also the [vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I will try this approach.